# Files not getting deleted using rsync --delete

Tags: bash, git, rsync, git-ls-files

rsync --delete does not work if the input for files is given by git ls-files

This is for syncing the two git repositories, wherein one is original and other is rsync backed up version.

I want files from some sub-directories of orig_repo to be synced in sync_repo, including the files that are deleted in orig_repo to be deleted in sync_repo.

The below code syncs both directories, the only problem is it does not delete files at destination end which are no longer present in the source directory.

`git ls-files -z sub_dir1/ sub_dir2/ | rsync --omit-dir-times --chmod=u+w --files-from=- -av0 source_repo/ destination_repo/`

I tried to add --delete flag like below:

`git ls-files -z sub_dir1/ sub_dir2/ | rsync --omit-dir-times --chmod=u+w --files-from=- -av0 --delete source_repo/ destination_repo/`

It did not work. 
Reason being, when we delete the file as:
`git rm file1`

The git ls-files outputs individual file name and not the directory, so the deleted files are not known to destination end.
Hence, I tried

`find sub_dir1/ -type d -print | rsync --omit-dir-times --chmod=u+w --files-from=- -av0 --delete source_repo/ destination_repo/`

It syncs all files into destination_repo but not specific subdirectories (sub_dir1, sub_dir2) so it does not work as intended.

I need both the repositories should be synced properly.